# Error: invalid value 'precompiled-header' in '-x precompiled-header'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I had to create a `file.h` which I put into my *includes/ directory*.
I meet a problem when comes time to GCC:

The error I get is:

> error: invalid value 'precompiled-header' in '-x precompiled-header'

And I have absolutely no idea about what causes this!
Here is my main, ask me if you need to see more of my code.
I compile with this line of command : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.c includes/* srcs/* do-op.c`

```
#include "includes/ft.h"

int    main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int     a;
    int     b;
    char    c;

    (void)ac;
    a = ft_atoi(av[1]);
    b = ft_atoi(av[3]);
    c = av[2][0];
    ft_putnbr(ft_do_op(a, b, c));
}
```

Comment: The error should have nothing to do with your source, but with how you build it and the build system and the environment and possible IDE you're using. Please edit your question to include all that information.

Comment: `file.h ` ?? is that your header right? why are you using then `ft.h`?

Comment: Hi, my file.h is named ft.h

Comment: I compile with : gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.c includes/* srcs/* do-op.c

Comment: My IDE is Visual Studio Code, I code on MacOs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state that your command to build is:

```sh
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.c includes/* srcs/* do-op.c
```

That means you're compiling the header files, which you normally should not do. What you *should* do is tell the compiler where it can find the header files, which is done with the `-I` (upper case i) option:

```sh
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Iincludes main.c srcs/* do-op.c
```

Comment: It should probably be `srcs/*.c` too (assuming you accept wild-cards at all; I regard them sceptically in a compiler command line).